# What is a word that means both "to stop something" and "not going to start something"

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word to use in a policy document that means both "to stop doing something" and "that I'm not going to start something" ?

For instance:

- Key reasons not to run activity
- Key Reasons to stop activity

I want to turn into one sentence "Key Reasons to >something < the activity"

Comment: I recommend, in the interests of understandability to your readers, that you not try to compress this into one word, but to be explicit and say both 'stop if you are already doing it' and 'don't start if you're not'. Sometimes multiple words are better than one.

Comment: @mitch I agree and in the policy text I would certainly expand - however the reason of one word was for a title of the section. I should have been more explicit in the question that the reason for the need for one word was for a title.

Comment: So would "Key Reasons to Not Run an Activity" or  "Key Reasons for an Activity Not to Run" work? You don't always want to force a word into a slot but instead to reorder things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about **avoid**?

Which Oxford Living Dictioary defines [online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/avoid) as

> Keep away from or stop oneself from doing (something)

Thus you have

> Key Reasons to avoid the activity.

Which nicely fits the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

## Cease (verb)

[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cease)

> **come to an end** or **bring to an end.**
>
> > "The doctor has a duty to inform the patient that driving should cease and the patient has a duty to act on that advice."

Your sample sentence: ***Key reasons to cease the activities.***

Answer (score -1):

There's a stock phrase in legalese for this - ["cease and desist"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cease_and_desist).

As @ubi hatt mentions, "cease" means to stop doing something; whereas "desist" means to abstain from doing something in the future.

Putting them together in this form encapsulates what you're trying to say; it's not a single word, but it's a commonly used short phrase that should be clear to most people.